# How do I obtain the text of the image associated with a Wordpress blog featured image?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

The following code is good for obtaining the post URL and title:

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 4 );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
  ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <br />
  <?php
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

However what I need is to obtain the text/url of the featured image including the path but not print it to the screen. The purpose of doing this is so that I can create a custom-sized image using ImageMagick convert and display that to the screen not the original image.

I'll be doing something like

```
convert "$image" -resized (my custom size) -strip 400x/$image
```

The convert code is a little more complicated as I intend to create large square thumbs, but that is the goal. I will then be posting the images in a wall style gallery of square thumbs on a page along with links to the individual posts.

Is there anything like the_featured_image() that will get me the image which I can then set as a variable and run the convert code?

Comment: Do you mean the post thumbnail? the_post_thumbnail()

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` to get URL of featured image or false if there is none.
So inside your `foreach` loop

```
$thumb_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full'); //can also be $post->ID
if($thumb_url)
{
    //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: That's good, works. How would I take the_title(); and get that into a variable like $the_title and do what I want with it rather than print to the screen?

Comment: @BobM `get_the_title()` or `$post->post_title`